# Certain entries in bib file not showing up in compiled bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

so I'm trying to compile a document and while the references are mostly working fine, when I compile the bibliography some of my references are not showing up.  Here's an example of a few I'm having this problem with:

```
@article{benmelech2012,
  title={Securitization without adverse selection: {T}he case of {CLO}s},
  author={Benmelech, Efraim and Dlugosz, Jennifer and Ivashina, Victoria},
  journal={Journal of Financial Economics},
  volume={106},
  number={1},
  pages={91--113},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{cantor2001,
  title={Moody’s investor service response to the consultative article 
  issued by the Basel Committee on Bank Supervision ``A new capital adequacy 
  framework''},
  author={Cantor, Richard},
  journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
  volume={25},
  pages={171--185},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

I've been trying to find a pattern or something wrong but I haven't been able to, any ideas?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  do you have `\cite` entries for these items in your file?  if not, you can add `\nocite{*}` to force them (and any  other non-appearing items) into your bibliography.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind just figured out these were all sources that were cited in the body of the text so I just needed to call `\nocite{*}`.